# How to store functions and arguments to execute later?

Tags: c#, callback

Suppose I have a 3 functions:

```
void A(int i){...}
void B(bool b, string s){...}
void C(float f, double d, char c){...}
```

In my application, in a given moment, I open a popup that has a button. My popup has a controller (called `PopupController`). It has references for everything in the popup and includes the function `OnButtonPress()`, called by the button at pressing.

My question is how to make the popup button execute those 3 functions with given parameter?

```
...
var popupController = PopupController.CreateInstance();
//I wanna execute this only at button press:
A(1);
B(true, "s");
C(1, 2, 'c');
```

How can I do this? I'm allowed to create whatever is needed to store these functions in the PopupController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delegates; for example

```
Action thing = () => A(1);
```

or

```
EventHandler handler = delegate {
    A(1);
    B(true, "s");
    C(1, 2, 'c');
};
```

then invoke that delegate later when needed, for example `thing();` or `handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);`.

this is even easier if the button-press is itself an event:

```cs
btn.Click += delegate {
    A(1);
    B(true, "s");
    C(1, 2, 'c');
};
```